# rosbridge publish to /joy_node: Error Received a message without an op

Tags: ros-kinetic, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish joystick movements to the /cmd_vel topic and the /joy_node topic from rosbridge Android.
While publishing to the /cmd_vel node works perfectly fine, publishing to /joy_node fails with the Error: "Received a message without an op." over the same connection to the ROSbridge master.

My coding:

```
....
   private float joy_axes[] = {0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f};
    private int joy_buttons[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    private int sequence_ID = 0;
    private long time_stamp_sec= System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    private long timestamp_nsec=222234283;
    private long time_stamp_prev;
    private String frame_id="";

private void onLoginSuccess() throws JSONException {
        // we advertise the ROS topic node we want to use for the Joystick (cmd_vel supports only the analog axis movements,
        // the joy node is the "real" ROS topic to publish all joystick features)
        Advertise("/cmd_vel", "geometry_msgs/Twist");
        Advertise("/joy_node", "sensor_msgs/Joy");
        connected_to_ros =true;
        connected_to_ros_message = "Connected to ROS Server: " + message;

        // send a test message to /cmd_vel ***** this works
        String cmdvel = "{\"op\":\"publish\",\"topic\":\"/cmd_vel\",\"msg\":{\"linear\":{\"x\":" + joy_axes[0] + ",\"y\":" + joy_axes[1] + ",\"z\":" + joy_axes[2] + "},\"angular\":{\"x\":" + joy_axes[3] + ",\"y\":" + joy_axes[4] + ",\"z\":" + joy_axes[5] + "}}}";
        client.send(cmdvel);

        //build the json array for the axes and buttons
        JSONArray json_joy_axes= new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < joy_axes.length; i++) {
            json_joy_axes.put(joy_axes[i]);
        }
        JSONArray json_joy_buttons= new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < joy_buttons.length; i++) {
            json_joy_buttons.put(joy_buttons[i]);
        }

        //send a test message to /joy_node **** this fails
        String joynode = "{\"op\":\"publish\",\"topic\":\"/joy_node\",\"msg\":{\"header\":{\"seq\": " + sequence_ID + ",\"stamp\":{\"secs\": " + time_stamp_sec + ",\"nsecs\": " + timestamp_nsec + "},\"frame_id\": " + frame_id + "},\"axes\":" + json_joy_axes +",\"buttons\":" + json_joy_buttons + "}}";
        client.send(joynode);
    }
```

I read here in this forum that rosbridge doesnt have a dedicated error handling for the parsing od json obects and that the error received indicates some problem with the json object definition.
So I verified the json string in JSONlint and it appears valid and consistent with the message type definition at http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Joy.html

What is wrong with my json object here? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344352/rosbridge-publish-to-/joy_node:-error-received-a-message-without-an-op/) by [mtbsteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/51121/mtbsteve/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-17**:
Not an answer, but a comment on something I noticed in your code:

> // we advertise the ROS topic node we want to use for the Joystick (cmd_vel supports only the analog axis movements,
>
> // the joy node is the "real" ROS topic to publish all joystick features)

`cmd_vel` is a topic (not a node), and it carries `geometry_msgs/Twist` messages. Those have no direct relationship with joysticks. They only encode a linear and angular velocity.

`joy` is a topic (the node is called `joy_node`) which carries `sensor_msgs/Joy` messages. Those do have a relationship with joysticks, in that they "Report the state of a joysticks axes and buttons".

`Joy` messages can be used to calculate values for a `Twist` message, but the two are not related directly, nor do they have to be used together necessarily (in fact, `Twist` is used for many purposes not even remotely related to joysticks).

**Comment by [mtbsteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/51121/mtbsteve/) on 2020-02-17**:
Yes I know. Thats why I am trying to use the /joy topic. I implemented the /cmd_vel topic only to verify that rosbridge is operational and to rule out any problems with the websocket connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit:

I just noticed this part in your `String joynode`:

```
[..] \"frame_id\": " + frame_id + "}, [..]
```

`frame_id` is a string, so it must be quoted, even in JSON.

I would expect something like this:

```
[..] \"frame_id\": \"" + frame_id + "\"}, [..]
```

note the additional `\"` surrounding the `frame_id`.

Unless whatever library you're using for emitting JSON takes care of this itself, I suspect that is actually the problem (if you're not using any library for serialising Java objects to JSON, you could consider using one, as it could prevent issues with quoting and general JSON layout).

Your comment about "an empty frame_id string" working seems to point to the same cause, as you don't pass an empty `frame_id` variable, but an explicit `\"\"`.

---

Original answer: I haven't checked this in any way, but while reading [wiki/joy: Nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/joy#Nodes) and comparing it with the code you show, I noticed this:

> ```
> Advertise("/joy_node", "sensor_msgs/Joy");
> ```

The topic to publish `sensor_msgs/Joy` messages on is called `joy`. The *node* that typically does this would be called `joy_node`.

Your code appears to be publishing to a *topic* called `joy_node`, which, if your downstream consumers expect the regular topic, will result in no messages being received by those subscribers. This could explain why you get the error your report (but it might also not).

You may want to run `roswtf` after you have started up your application (including all ROS nodes). I suspect it will report some unconnected subscribers and/or publishers.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mtbsteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/51121/mtbsteve/) on 2020-02-17**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn I tried advertising of /joy and publishing to /joy instead of /joy_node makes no difference. I still get the same error.
roswtf runs with "No errors or warnings". So the problem must be somewhere in the json string I am using, or with the rosbridge kinetic implementation for this topic...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-18**:\

> I tried advertising of /joy and publishing to /joy instead of /joy_node makes no difference. I still get the same error.

regardless, `/joy` would be the appropriate topic. Not `/joy_node`.

**Comment by [mtbsteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/51121/mtbsteve/) on 2020-02-18**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn adding the quotes to the frame_id variable fixed it. But since the frame_id is left empty also in the „official“ kinetic/melodic ros joy package implementation, I guess it can also be hardcoded in the rosbridge  json object as I initially did.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-18**:
Yes. A `frame_id` doesn't make much sense for a `Joy` message.